# Extension method to convert string to Cron format

Tags: c#, cron

I have a repeating schedule in (dayOfWeek) (hour) (minutes) (seconds)
That is passed in as a string. MONDAY-18-20-00
I would like to convert that as a CRON Expression and store it in the database.
What would be the easiest way to do this ?

Comment: you can use this and write extension method for make it easier https://stackoverflow.com/a/9398804/11104908

Comment: Probably best to store as `dayOfWeek tinyint` and `timeOfDay time`

Comment: You have 2 questions here, how create a Cron Expression, or how to use a database? Have you used Cron, do you know the basic structure? how far did you get?

Comment: @TheGeneral I am asking a simple way to convert a (dayOfWeek) (hour) (minutes) (seconds) to a cron expression that I can save to database as a string.

Comment: Let me know if the answer doesn't work, or I have misunderstood and ill delete it

Answer (score 0):

If you are just needing to convert the current format into a *cron* format, then the following may work for you

```
var weirdInput = "MONDAY-18-20-00";

var split = weirdInput.Split("-");

var result = $"{split[3]} {split[2]} {split[1]} ? * {split[0][..3]}";
```

**Output Cron**

```
// At 18:20:00pm, on every Monday, every month
00 20 18 ? * MON
```